# Building/running IOS app from command line with external icon files

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, xcodebuild, xcconfig

I am trying to build/run my IOS app from command line. To build the app, the command which i give in shell script is as follows:

```
xcodebuild  -sdk "${TARGET_SDK}" -xcconfig "${CONFIG_FILE_PATH}"  -configuration Debug
```

and this works wonders. But I also want to give app icons externally. Can i do that with xcodebuild command ie. referring to the icon files in some external folder and overwriting the ones selected in xcode editor for a target.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a custom environment variable in the xcodebuild command line to pass the location of app icons. You can google for the instructions for passing the environment variable to xcodebuild, here is [one link](http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/05/17/passing-user-variable-to-xcodebuild) that describes it well. With this environment variable you can create a new build phase (Select your target, click Editor->Add Build Phase->Add Run Script Build Phase). Write a script that will copy the icon files if the environment variable exists.